# what glue should i use when making 5, 12 V connectors (plugs)?

Tags: wiring, cables, insulator

At the moment I'm making 5.5 x 2.1 mm DC connectors.  The connectors are typical solder lug types like you'd find at the big online stores.  I'd feel better about these if I could insulate the lugs -- the power and ground will be somewhat close together and I'm worried that if the connector is hit or crushed the lugs will short and damage the power supply.

About 30 hours ago I squirted some Liquid Nails on a board.  Today I tested the resistance and I got about a meg Ohm.  This was a pretty sloppy measurement:  I get different measurements depending on whether the probe pierces the surface, how close they are, the reading is far from stable, and so on and so on.  The point is, I'm guessing in my application, with the lugs being about 3mm apart, I'd get only 100K and maybe a lot less.  (As a control, if I merely touch the board the meter shows an open circuit.)  I'm about to test 5 minute epoxy the same way.

The question is, is there something I could use that makes more sense than me trying to guess?

Answer (score 0):

Well, duh.  I forgot about the so-called liquid electrical tape, which is just a paintable rubber that can be had at most "big box" stores.  I had some once, but it long ago hardened beyond usability.  So I'm guessing that would be pretty good stuff.

At any rate, the 5 minute epoxy tested as open circuit, so I'm going to use that, since it'll save me a trip to the store in these covid-19 times.